# Setting navigation item title issue.. why my navigation item seems many?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to change the title of navigation bar but it seems somewhat confusing..
I did `self.navigationItem.title = "ipsum"` or `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "ipsum"` and so on.. but it fails..

It only succeeds changing the title when trying `self.title = "ipsum"` but it is not what I want because it causes tabBarItem's title to change too.

I tried debugging and found out strange result.

[image]

as you see the picture above.. there seems to be more than two navigationBar so when `self.navigationItem.title = "ipsum"` it actually changes some other or invisible navigationItem's title so that I can see from the log.

But the UI stays "lorem". Tell me if you figure something out! What am I missing?

**EDIT 1:**

Main.storyboard
[image]

Menu.storyboard
[image]

I put NavigationController in TabBarController and refactored NavigationController to another storyboard reference.

`self.navigationItem.title = "ipsum"` is called in the viewDidLoad() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now View controllers are:

ViewController1 attached to item1:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title="View1"

    }
```

ViewController2 attached to item2:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title="View2"

    }
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used `self.navigationItem.title="????"`.  It worked for me:)

Comment: Yeah.. usually it ends only with that.. but it doesn't work for me .. ;(

Comment: I edited putting storyboard configuration.. if you want to check more .. tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should always use just

```
navigationItem.title = ""
```

because each controller has it's own navigationItem and if you trying to set title like this - self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title you possible set it to wrong place.